# Is bookmarking posts possible so I can find them easily later?

Tags: support, questions, bookmarks

Is there any way to set aside certain posts that I read here by, maybe, bookmarking or flagging them, so that I can find those posts later, to refer to them easily or to keep track of and see their contents later?

For example, I've been discussing something with some RL (real life) friends and I asked about the subject here. While reading answers that I received about it, I found myself browsing through related posts. Later, I was talking with my RL friends about the material in those related posts - and they wanted to see them.

It would have been nice if I had had those posts bookmarked or something so that I could've found them quickly when my friends asked to see them.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can "favorite" (star) any *question*, mainsite or meta, by clicking on the star below the downvote arrow.

When you have favorited a post a few things will happen:

- it will enter the list that lives in your profile-->activity-->favorites, thus creating an easily-accessed list of "bookmarked" questions;
- the visible count under the (now golden-colored) star under the question's score will increment by 1;
- the question's owner may earn a [badge](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/badges).

(See more at the main meta.SE FAQ entry on favorited questions [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/53585).)

If it's an *answer* you really want to easily come back to, there's no in-site functionality that will help there. Either favorite the question and hopefully you'll remember (upon scrolling) which answer tickled your fancy, or maybe you're better served by your browser's bookmarking capabilities.

(Flagging them would also create a trail you could find. However, the trail's hard*er* for you to find, you'd be making more work for moderators, and you'd rack up a whole lotta declined flags which'll drive down your trustworthiness as perceived by the software. Go ahead and stick to the favorites.)

Comment: Beautiful! Exactly what I need to know! Thank you!